# How to move nuget path in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

**Issue:** I am trying to run a command `PM> add-migration testing`.

**Detail:** I know why I am getting this error. Due to security reasons, our company doesn't allow us to run any files inside `C:\Users\name\...` . so `init.ps1` is getting blocked since i cant run inside that folder.

To fix, I moved my Visual Studio project code folder to the following path: `C:\adminrun\repos`. Here I admin access and I am allow to run any files. This lets me run project but `init.ps1` is still inside `C:\Users\name\.nuget\packages` (this path is blocked)

**Question:** can I run `add-migration` command without PM?

**Error:**

> & : File C:\Users\name.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\6.0.13\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
>
> At line:1 char:45
>
> - ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users\name.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityfram ...
> - 
> - CategoryInfo: SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

`C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Since the original scripts assume the default paths are well available, you will have to completely customize all scripts to adapt to your unique situation. Nobody here can easily help, as they don't fall into the same setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1, change the downloaded NuGet package storage location:**

1. According to the following file path, find a file named "NuGet.Config", or search for the file directly.

   C:\Users{system username}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
2. Open the "NuGet.Config" file, we can see the original file content as follows:

   ```
   xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
    <configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    packageSources>
   configuration>
   ```
3. Replace its contents with the following and save:

   ```
   xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?  
   <configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    packageSources>


    <config>

        <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=" The new path where you want the NuGet package to be stored " />


        <add key="repositoryPath" value=" The new path where you want the NuGet package to be stored " />
    config>
   configuration>
   ```

**Step2, modify the VS offline package reference address:**

1. According to the following file path, find a file named "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config", or search for the file directly.

   C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config
2. Open the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config" file, we can see the original file content as follows:

   ```
   xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
    <configuration>
    <packageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\"/>
   packageSources>
   configuration>
   ```
3. Replace its contents with the following and save:

   ```
   xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
    <configuration>
    <packageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value=" The new path where you want the NuGet package to be stored "/>
   packageSources>


    <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=" The new path where you want the NuGet package to be stored " />
    config>
    configuration>
   ```

**Step3, verify that the modified new path is successful:**

Re-open a project with VS, uninstall a reference package in the project and reinstall it, find the reference item in the project reference list, right-click to open the property panel, in the "Path" column, we can clearly find the referenced The address has become the new address we just set.